# Bugs on KendoUI Web 2014.1.318 - Incompatible with jQuery 1.9.x when running in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, telerik

Just want to report there is a bug in KendoUI Web 2014.1.318. Below is how I generate this error:

> 1. Use jQuery 1.9.x and above.
> 2. Use KendoUI Web 2014.1.318
> 3. Create a view with a Kendo Splitter. Left side create a Kendo Grid and Right side create any Kendo UI.
> 4. View it in Chrome. Only can see one side of splitter.
>
> No problem in KendoUI Web 2013.3.1119.
>   No problem if using jQuery
>   1.8.3 No problem if run in IE or FF.

This is the only bug I report and the last bug. I am Open Source license, the last version I can get from KendoUI is 2014.1.318. So, even if Telerik have fix the bug, I won't be able to use it. Bye bye Kendo. Miss you forever.

Comment: Tested without Splitter today. Still having the same problem where the Grid does not return any content in Chrome when using KENDO UI Web 2014.1.318 with jQuery 1.9 and above. Obviously it is a bug in Kendo Grid (rule out Splitter).

Comment: When I check in Chrome Console, this is the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function".

Comment: I found this: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-createdocumentfragment-of-undefined-in-chrome. The problem similar like mine, work in IE & FF but not Chrome. Work in jQuery 1.9 and below but not 1.9 and above. Looks like is the jQuery bugs. I will use 1.8.3 temporary until jQuery fix the bug.

Comment: I found the bug in KendoUI Web 2014.1.318 and above + jQuery 1.9 and above + latest Chrome: Follow this step. In an empty HTML (HTML1) page, use AJAX call to load another HTML Page (HTML2). In HTML2 page, load a Kendo Grid that will load a datasource. The script in HTML2 page will run but no datasource display and there is an error "Uncaught TypeError, Undefined is not a function". If you run HTML2 page directly, no problem. I think this is Kendo UI Grid bug. Unfortunately, even Kendo have fix the bug, the open source community won't get the latest bug fix anymore. :(